# Send captured group as array index to sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

```
file=/home/root/customers_and_contacts.txt
month[1]="January"
month[2]="Febuary"
month[3]="March"
month[4]="April"
month[5]="May"
month[6]="June"
month[7]="July"
month[8]="August"
month[9]="September"
month[10]="October"
month[11]="November"
month[12]="December"

cat $file | sed "s/\b[0-9]\([0-9]\)-\?\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\?\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b/$(month[\1])"
```

For simplicity sakes, I have created the above document. Basically customers_and_contacts.txt contains a date that I would like to convert the month to the actual name of the month.

`Month[0]` seems to work

`\1` seems to work

When you put them together, it doesn't

Edit ----

Let's assume the input file contains n number of lines that look like the following:

```
  08-06-1998

  02-03-2014
```

The output file should look like the following

```
   August 06-1998

   February 03-2014
```

Comment: You can't do it like this. The command substitution `$(month[\1])` gets expanded by the shell before sed ever gets to see the whole command. What does your input file look like?

Comment: [edit] your question to show us concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. So far you've only shown us a script that **doesn't** do whatever it is you want to do but haven't shown us what it is you **do** want to do so we'd just be guessing at how best to help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: post your input file `/home/root/customers_and_contacts.txt` contents and expected result

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a bug: To access an element of bash array, you use braces:

```
${month[1]}
```

Otherwise it will complain about `month[1] command not found` or something.

Secondly, bash will expand all variables first before sending the command to the sub-shell, so assuming you fixed your bug above, you will be sending the following command (`${month[\1]}` expands to `January` since \1 is just 1 in bash):

```
cat /home/root/customers_and_contacts.txt | \
  sed "s/\b[0-9]\([0-9]\)-\?\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\?\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b/January"
```

Finally, the original design will not do what you intended, since it requires multiple replacement logic beyond a sed single pattern replacement.

You can do multiple replacement logic in sed using multiple `-e` options:

```
cat $file | \
  sed -e "s/..1../..${month[1]}../" \
      -e "s/..2../..${month[2]}../" \
      -e "s/..3../..${month[3]}../" \
      -e..
```

You can fill in the blank (..) with your original code.

Comment: "Bug" was just a typo. As stated above, I can get it to expand the array if the index specified is hard coded. In contrast, I can get the captured group to show as well. But when combining them, it does not work.

Comment: Read the second part of my answer regarding the multiple replacement logic. A single replacement using sed will only replace one month number (in your code, that is January.)